# Написание высокопроизводительного REST endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Допустим мы пишем REST endpoint на RoR, которая позволяет пользователю удалять записи. Мы ожидаем, что пользователь будет посылать запросы на массовое удаление записей. Система должна обладать высокой производительностью и быть созданной в сжатые сроки. На что при проектировании следует обратить внимание **в первую** очередь?

В своё время уже писал подобный интерфейс для удаления пользователя с веб-сайта. Вслед за пользователем, каскадно удалялись все его данные (в среднем 1000 фотографий в 4-х экземплярах на AWS), что просто стопорило сервер на 30 секунд. Проблему решил созданием костыля, который создавал для операции удаления отдельный поток. Не хотелось бы снова вставать на те же грабли.

Comment: создание отдельного потока - это не совсем костыль. Но кто его знает, сколько удалять в этот раз решите. И скорее всего все упрется в базу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## На отложенное выполнение долгих действий

Раз для этого действия вы имеете возможность создавать отдельный поток, то вам необязательно завершать это действие **до** отправки ответа клиенту. А для подобных действий принято создавать **очередь задач**. В качестве канонического примера подобных действий обычно приводят отсылку электронной почты, но у вас нашлось действие немного другой природы, не менее подходящее.

С ними есть контроль над тем, сколько максимум таких тяжёлых задач может исполняться параллельно, и можно настроить количество очередй так, чтобы система не ложилась. И более того, можно менять это количество прямо во время работы (это больше задача из области администрирования).

Структура таких очередей обычно следующая:

- Есть **хранилище задач**. Это может быть специализированный сервер для обмена сообщениями (RabbitMQ), а может быть хранилище данных общего назначения (Redis, PostgreSQL). Там хранятся задачи, требующие выполнения.
- Есть **сервер** (воркер, рабочий процесс), который забирает по одной записи из **хранилища задач** *в порядке очереди* (порядок может быть навязан хранилищем данных, но не обязательно) и выполняет что написано.
- Есть **клиент**, который добавляет записи в **хранилище задач**.

Из современных реализаций из экосистемы Ruby могу подсказать следующее:

- **[ActiveJob](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activejob)** — своеобразный адаптер [для разных реализаций очередей](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html), появился в Rails 4.2. Предсказуемо, почти вся функциональность, специфичная для конкретных реализаций, глубоко закопана или недоступна.
- **[Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)** — самый популярный вариант. Задачи хранит в **Redis**. Выполняют задачи запускаемые специально для этого процессы. Поддерживает ништяки вроде назначения задач на заданное время.

  - Надёжность, к сожалению, так себе: воркеры забирают задачи из хранилища и атомарно с забором затирают их там, чтобы одну задачу не могло схватить несколько воркеров. Если процесс, выполнявший задачу, упадёт, задача исчезнет вникуда. Решение есть в платной версии, но вы понимаете.
- **[Hutch](https://github.com/gocardless/hutch)** — малоизвестный вариант. По сути, является упрощённым клиентом к **RabbitMQ**, серверу обмена сообщениями. Упрощённым, т. к. возможностей абсолютный минимум и обмен сообщениями происходит через единственный *topic exchange*.

  - *Topic exchange* можно использовать не только для очереди задач. Поэтому Hutch не позиционируется как очередь задач, но как средство обмена сообщениями между сервисами.
- **[Que](https://github.com/chanks/que)** — довольно новый и интересный вариант. Задачи хранит в отдельной таблице PostgreSQL. Может пользоваться всеми гарантиями ACID наравне с остальными данными и меняться в транзакциях вместе с ними.

  - "Захват" задач производится через advisory lock (рекомендательную блокировку) на которую БД не обращает внимания, приложение может явно указать, что оно хочет к ним как-то относиться. Факт блокировки фиксируется на уровне соединения в оперативной памяти. Если соединение умрёт, блокировка отвалится и запись будет доступна для других. В этом есть и проблема: запускать воркеров Que с доступом к БД через pgbouncer нельзя.

Есть, конечно, и другие. Можно сориентироваться по [списку поддержки ActiveJob](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html).